# Magento2 Category Registry issue to get Ids

Tags: magento2, registry

- List item

When I open direct products from the search bar these thumbnails are not working because these not get parent ids. I think its registry issue when I will come from the menu then its work.

---

```
 if( $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category'))//get current category 
            {
            $catId =  $category->getId();
            $catName =  $category->getName();
            $parent_ids = $category->getParentIds();

            }

            //print_r($parent_ids); exit(); 
            //$subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($catId);
            // print_r($subcategory->getData()); exit();
            //$subcats = $subcategory->getChildrenCategories(); ?>

           <li class="slide">

                 <?php if(in_array('22',$parent_ids)) : ?>


                <img onclick="imagezoomer('<?php echo $imageUrl ?>', '<?php echo $fullimageUrl ?>')" data-id="smallthumbs-<?php echo $_product->getId();?>" width="85" height="85" data-img="<?php //echo $productImagedata; ?>" alt="<?php echo $child->getLabel(); ?>"  src="<?php echo $productImage; ?>"/>
                <?php else : ?>
                 <img data-id="smallthumbs-<?php echo $_product->getId();?>" data-img="<?php //echo $productImagedata; ?>" width="85" height="85" alt="<?php echo $child->getLabel(); ?>"  src="<?php echo $productImage; ?>"/>

                <?php endif; ?>
              </li>

              <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
              <?php endif; ?>
```

[image: o 2]

Comment: You are using $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category'); to get the category for the product?

Comment: yes its work when i open product using menu categories.

Comment: when i direct open product registry not save id thats why its not work that i want

Comment: OK,This is because the current_category will fetch the category data if you open the product from the category page. Please share, the products are on your website having multiple categories?